# bullet chart configuration in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Given a bullet chart like the following using Highcharts:

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bullet-graph

[image]

- Is it possible to have more than one target value?
  We are trying to keep track of many targets against a particular bar.
- How do you change the width of the bar? I can't seem to find the settings, there are settings for the target, but I can't find the right ones for the bar.

Here is the chart code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
    chart: {
        marginTop: 40
    },
    title: {
        text: '2017 YTD'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['<span class="hc-cat-title">Revenue</span><br/>U.S. $ (1,000s)']
    },
    yAxis: {
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 150,
            color: '#666'
        }, {
            from: 150,
            to: 225,
            color: '#999'
        }, {
            from: 225,
            to: 9e9,
            color: '#bbb'
        }],
        title: null
    },
    series: [{
        data: [{
            y: 275,
            target: 250
        }]
    }],
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b> (with target at {point.target})'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in Highcharts to add two targets, but by doing some tricky override of `drawPoints` bullet series prototype function, you can achieve the expected effect. Here is the example of using it: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6wvbc1kb/

After applying this override you should be able to set the `minTarget` field inside of your point object. Then the second target indicator will appear on the chart.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have more than one target value?

Yes, but in this case, you'll have multiple axes. You cannot have multiple targets on one axis as the `target` accepts only an integer. 
For this, you can add the additional data in `series` like:

```
series: [{
    data: [{
        y: 275,
        target: 250,
    }, {
        y: 275,
        target: 240,
    }]
}]
```

[Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bullet.data)
The label on the xAxis can be set by adding the text in 'categories' array:

```
categories: [
    '<span class="hc-cat-title">Revenue</span><br/>U.S. $ (1,000s)',
    '<span class="hc-cat-title">Profit</span><br/>U.S. $ (1,000s)'
]
```

> How do you change the width of the bar

This can be done setting the `pointWidth` property like:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointWidth: 15
    }
}
```

You can see this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/64dvb08n/8/) with these options set.

Comment: thanks for that, unfortunately our requirement is to draw multiple target bars on the same series, so I am going to have to figure out how to draw the additional ones myself

Comment: can start point be non zero number?. like start point from 40. I see it takes from 0 always. Also, irrespective of end of last series i.e `to: 9e9,` if the number is 900 but the target is say 300, maximum it shows is up to 350. can this last margin be showed in the graph?.